# OData JSON query not working

Tags: javascript, json, odata

The below seconary function call for OData works for other fields but I'm calling it again for another field and it is not working. This time the alert is displaying. paramField is valid and works in SQL when I do the odata select manually. What would cause readyState or status to not be good (hence, firing the alert)?

```
function getFieldData_any(retrieveReq,paramField) {
    if (retrieveReq.readyState == 4 && retrieveReq.status == 200) { 
        var retrieved = this.parent.JSON.parse(retrieveReq.responseText).d;
        EntityField = retrieved.results[0][paramField];
    }
    else
    {
        alert('readyState not 4 or status not 200');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your console, specifically the Network tab and see if the server gave back an error.

Comment: Got it working. Apparently the OData Select wanted the guid identifier even though the record guid field did not contain braces.  example:   "OpportunityId eq guid'" + id + "'". I thought it only needed the guid word if it contained braces? Thank you for the suggestion tymeJV but I wouldn't know where to look at that. I'm running the javascript inside CRM 2011.

Answer (score 0):

About the format of OData Primitive literal, please refer to the OData spec

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/

In OData-ABNF, You will find the format of Guid should be as following

guid = “guid” SQUOTE 8*HEXDIG “-” 4*HEXDIG “-” 4*HEXDIG “-” 12*HEXDIG SQUOTE